# При клике на td в table достать информацию остальных td которые относятся к ним

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

Есть таблица, которая заполняется информацией из БД (циклом) 
Нажму например на ASD (Service Name), мне нужно достать Description, Project Manager и все что находится в этой строке. Не подскажете как можно это сделать? Возможно ли оно вообще, если я тупо прохожусь циклом по всем элементам в базе данных и нигде не сохраняю их, а просто отрисовываю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<%
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        int ProjectID = rs.getInt(1);
                        String Project = rs.getString(4);
                        String Description = rs.getString(5);
                        String Service = rs.getString(7);
                        String Date = rs.getString(8);
                        String pr = rs.getString(9);
                        if(rs.wasNull()) {
                            pr = "";
                        }
                        String type = rs.getString(10);
                        if(rs.wasNull()) {
                            type = "";
                        }
                        String SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM FILE WHERE projectId = " + ProjectID;
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uiModal1" class="TDName"><%=Project%></td>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uiModal1" class="TDDesc"><%=Description%></td>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uiModal1" class="TDServ"><%=pr%></td>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uiModal1" class="TDServ"><%=Service%></td>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uiModal1" class="TDType"><%=type%></td>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uiModal1" class="TDAuth"><%=isAdmin%></td>
                    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uiModal1" class="TDDate"><%=Date%></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так можно пройтись по всем значениям соседних ячеек.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).siblings().addBack().each(function(){
      console.log($(this).text())
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Думаю это менее удобный вариант, так как не включаются выбранные элементы, но он тоже верный. Плюсанул

Comment: Поправил, чтобы кликнутый выбирался

Comment: Спасибо дружище!! Помогло

Answer (score 1):

Ну при клике достать данные из строки не сложно.

```js
$('table td').click(function() {
  var all_td = $(this).parent().find('td'); // Выборка всех td из строки кликнутого td

  // Делаете, что нужно с этими ячейками. Подробнее смотрите в документации по jQuery иил JS (содержимое элемента, атрибуты элемента, воможно еще nth-child псевдо класс

  $(all_td).each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).text())
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>211</td>
    <td>312</td>
    <td>413</td>
    <td>514</td>
    <td>615</td>
    <td>999916</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

> мне просто в   вашу функцию добавить? Или нужно в table td эту функцию привязать ? Типо `<td onclick="blabla">` ??

В JS файл, который нужно будет подключить, либо в `<script type=text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: мне просто в <script> </script> вашу функцию добавить? Или нужно в table td эту функцию привязать ? Типо <td onclick="blabla"> ??

Comment: обновлен код с информацией

Comment: Спасибо большое дружище!!

Comment: Можешь сказать спасибо, псюсанув ответ )